# "Клевый" — откуда пошло слово?

Tags: жаргон, этимология

Есть сленговое словечко "клевый". Интересно, его происхождение — от рыбаков, в основе "клев рыбы"? Или что-то другое?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я думаю что да, только не прямо, а опосредовано через снасть.
Есть такое представление у рыбаков как "клевая" снасть - обычно блесна, искусственная муха или там мормышка - то, на что клюёт.
Отсюда ряд: клевый > удачливый > успешный > выигрышный > {крутой/нехилый/знатный... }

Первоначально значение, впрочем, было более узким и относилось главным образом к одежде или внешности "клевого"/"клевой" персоны.

Answer (score 5):

Из В.Даля

КЛЕВЫЙ
ряз., тамб., твер., влад. клюжий, клювый, хороший, пригожий, красивый, казистый, добротный; выгодный или полезный. Это клевое дело, путь будет. Клевая невеста. Клевашный парень ниж.-мак. старательный, работящий, путный.

КЛЕК муж. калуж. самое лучшее, отборное, первый разбор; цвет, краса чего. Что ни самый КЛЕК, то и выбрали. Тут все народ КЛЕК, отборная сволочь.

| Игра городки или чурки.
| Лягушачья икра, норост, вакотье. См. также клекнуть.

Comment: Как бывает полезно заглянуть в старый словарь!

Answer (score 3):

Корень *КЛЪВ* обозначает накалывание, что также может подходить и к украшениям (фибулы, броши, серьги, за**клёп**ки).
**Клёк** — звукоподражательный корень (клёкот птиц, клик), обозначающий призыв (самца, самки), поэтому он мог выражать кричащие, вызывающие, привлекающие вещи.
КЛЁВ рыбы — это накалывание оной на клевец (острый крюк).
КЛЮВ птицы — это также острый крюк (клюк).

Answer (score 1):

В английском языке есть слово  "clever" – умный, ловкий, искусный, способный, талантливый (похоже на "клевый"). А есть глагол "to cleave" – раскалывать, разрезать, рассекать (то есть тоже что-то острое, режущее, как и в "клюв", "клев").

По-моему, достаточно показательное сходство. Еще можно вспомнить такое растение, как клевер (clover), которое является символом Святой Троицы, а четырехлистный клевер приносит удачу, благополучие (что очень и очень клево!).

Answer (score 1):

Вероятный ряд- КоЛ КЛюв КЛеВ . Смысловой ряд-  острый и твердый. крюк . пойманный . Далее клевый несет позитивную сторону какого - либо свойства.

Answer (score 0):

Словечко появилось в обиходе советских хиппи и заимствовано из английского языка. "Клёвый чувак" означало сообразительный парень, от английского "clever" – умный, ловкий, искусный, способный, талантливый.